# How to avoid duplicates in a Triggered Send Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

How do I avoid duplicates in a Triggered Send Data Extension?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Triggered Send Data Extension is meant to be a log, which is why they're created with a Data Extension Template.

I'd recommend using an [**Exclusion Script**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213980&language=en_US&type=1):

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("TRIGGERED_SEND_DE", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) > 1`

While this doesn't prevent all duplicates, it'll prevent people from getting more than one email.

You can de-duplicate the DE with with a Query Activity if the subscribers need to move to a Master Data Extension or something like that.

Comment: This exclusion script fetish is getting out of control.

Comment: FTFY: This exclusion script fetish is finally catching on.

Comment: Nah. The "OP" asked how to avoid "dupes" in a triggered send DE. In essence, Markus answered "choose your primary key wisely". If the calling application needs to understand its request has been rejected, it should handle it and tell the user. If the "OP" shares some other information that changes the use case, maybe Markus will be wrong and you'll be right. But, I don't see anything in the limited information that makes me believe that's true or make me jump into discussing exclusion scripts... nah.