# Marketing Cloud triggered send exactly once delivery

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I tried to skim the official Marketing Cloud doc but I didn't find a clear answer.

Is it possible to enforce an "exactly once" delivery for a triggered send?

The final goal would be to enforce that only one email is ever sent to a given email address for a specific triggered send executed via the REST API.

I've find the possible usage of an Exclusion Script (i.e. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/184793/57712) but I'm actually not sure if it is a viable and proper way to handle my desiderata.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer in the link you provided is the way to go. It is basically saving "do not send to this person if they already have a record in the logging data extension" - so as long as you are logging the triggered sends to a DE and referencing that same DE in your script, you're good to

Comment: Ok perfect @AnonWonderer, thanks a lot for your clarification.
I'll try to add the logging of the triggered sends to a DE.
Thanks again.